# Angular8 Date Convert

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-date-format

I need to convert the date to 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a'

From

```
Mon, 27 Dec 2021 17:32:52 GMT
```

To

```
27/12/2021 05:32:52 PM
```

I have tried the angular pipe but the output is wrong.

```
{{created_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a'}}
```

I am getting the below Output but the correct output supposed to be '27/12/2021 05:32:52 PM'

```
 27/12/2021 11:02:52 PM
```

Comment: Consider timezone-offsets/locale -> check https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate for more info..

Comment: @ 
iLuvLogix .Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formatDate(date, "dd-MM-y h:mm a", "en-US",'-0000');`

Comment: See- wasn't so difficult ;) Please consider to elaborate on this self-answer for future readers that encounter a similar issue in regards to time-offsets/locales..

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd [parameter](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#parameters) to DatePipe is `timezone` which is `undefined` by default. In such case the `DatePipe` will use the end-user's local system timezone.

Since `created_date` is in GMT, to get the result as `27/12/2021 05:32:52 PM` you can pass the timezone as:

```html
{{created_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss a' : 'GMT'}}
```